# What is an external nulling "resistor"?

Tags: operational-amplifier, input-offset-voltage

in the following datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP07.pdf

Which is a OP07 a high precision ultralow voltage offset OpAmp, it says in the datasheet.

> The accuracy and stability of the OP07, even at high gain, combined
>   with the freedom from external nulling have made the OP07 an industry
>   standard for instrumentation applications

what is external nulling?

Comment: I wrote an answer before checking for duplicates. There are of course a lot of duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a randomly chosen old op-amp, for example the [TL081](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082.pdf). The single-amp version will often have two pins named "offset null" or similar.

This is because they have a fairly large offset voltage that can cause problems if you want to amplify DC levels, and the offset voltage is different for each IC.

There are [many ways](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa045/sloa045.pdf) to connect these pins but normally it's just a trimpot connected to the pins, with the wiper connected to the most negative supply rail.

Answer (score 0):

Some opamps have a way of adjusting out the input voltage offset.  This is usually performed with resistors or a potentiometer between two pins brought out for that purpose.

Example from [Electronics-Notes](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/offset-null.php) (which also has a good description):

[image: Offset Null 1]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means adjusting the op amp input offset voltage error towards zero with components external to the op amp, such as trimmer potentiometer or resistors connected to op amp adjustment pins.